# About the access of the nested attributes in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Hi if any one can plz give the solution of the following error I m getting.**

I have two models PackageDeals and PackageDetails

In PackageDeals model i have the following code:-
`has_many :package_details
    has_many :image_sets
    accepts_nested_attributes_for  :package_details`

And in the PackageDetails model I have:

```
    belongs_to :package_deals
accepts_nested_attributes_for :package_deals
```

Now in the controller:

```
def new 
        @packages=PackageDeals.new(params[:package_deals])
                    @packages.package_details.build
```

end

Now inthe view I am using:

```
      <td><%= r.text_field :name, :class => 'space_bottom quote_request_form',:size=>17 %></td></tr>
        <tr><td><%= r.fields_for :package_details do |f| %></td></tr>

        some codes

        <%end%>
  <tr>
    <td><%= r.submit 'Create', :class => 'space_top' %></td></tr></table>
  <% end %>
```

Now I m getting this error while clicking new link in the view:

**uninitialized constant PackageDeals::PackageDetail**

**Any solution Please................**

Answer (score 1):

Check the spelling of model and association names:

Rails by default uses **singular form** in model names, *has_one* and *belongs_to* association names (e.g. `PackageDeal` and `belongs_to :package_deal`) and **plural** in *has_many* association names (e.g. `has_many :package_details`). More info: http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7

You can break the naming conventions, but then you'll need extra parameters on the associations. So it's recommended to stick to the defaults unless you have a strong reason not to. More info about those extra parameters: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to